# How to render inside a loop inside a JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like make this to work:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        let elements = {"0": "aaaaa"};
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <td>Elements</td>
                    <td>Contenu</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {Object.values(elements).map((element, index => {
                <span>
                    {element.value}
                </span>
                })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

}
```

I wanna have a render inside a object.entries loop inside a render

Comment: Why use `.entries` over putting the objects in an array? That's also not how `Object.entries` is used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: use `.map` instead

Comment: yes, but that's not the only thing. I will edit my ask in 1 minute

Comment: Object does not prototype an `entries` function. Also when you supply a callback function, make sure to `return`.

Comment: @DispénNém try to include _all_ relevant information in the question. Otherwise the edits could make the answers below useless

Comment: I edited my question and it still does not work

Comment: Try `(element, index) => ( <span> ... </span> )`. Or `(element, index) => { return  ( <span> ... </span> ) }`. Notice the difference with braces and curly braces there, and the closing brace for callback arguments.

Comment: Editing the question with input taken from answers by the community is pretty misleading, it's changed the bug itself. Try to stick with the answer that I posted and you should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    let elements = {"0": "aaaaa"};
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <td>Elements</td>
          <td>Contenu</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {Object.values(elements).map((element, index) => {
          return <span>
            {element}
          </span>
        })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

In your solution you were missing end of parentheses in `map` and `return` also in `map`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to map over the values of the Object `elements`, but drop the `.value` lookup on each element, as that will be undefined.

```js
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    let elements = {"0": "aaaaa"};
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <td>Elements</td>
          <td>Contenu</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {Object.values(elements).map((element, index) => (
          <span>
            {element}
          </span>
        ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

It's also worth point out that an Object isn't the best way to store a list of data, an Array would be much simpler. Like so:

```js
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    const elements = [
      'aaa',
      'bbb',
      'ccc'
    ];
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <td>Elements</td>
          <td>Contenu</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {elements.map((element, index) => (
          <span>
            {element}
          </span>
        ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` in the callback there. Unless you mean it to use `()`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your object values to an array using Object.values(your_object) and then map throw the array via the map method.